# Get ratio between different members of a column in the best performance

Tags: python, pandas

I have the df:

```
    ClientHostID    LoginDaysSum
0   70  4
1   70  2
2   71  11
3   71  2
4   79  37
5   79  1
6   79  1
7   80  18
8   80  6
9   87  29
10  87  1
11  88  88
12  88  2
13  88  1
14  88  1
15  88  1
16  88  1
```

It is sorted:

```
local_input_list.sort_values(['ClientHostID', 'LoginDaysSum'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
```

What I want is for every ClientHostID to get the ratio between his largest LoginDaysSum to his second largest LoginDaysSum (the result will be):

```
    ClientHostID    ratio
0   70  2
1   71  5.5
2   79  37
3   80  3
4   87  29
5   88  22
```

I manage to get it with:

```
 df = df.groupby(['ClientHostID'], sort=False)['LoginDaysSum'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] / x.iloc[1]).reset_index(name='ratio')
```

But the catch is using apply is too heavy on the performance...

I thought about doing something like:

```
largest = df.groupby(['ClientHostID']).first()
drop_largest = df.drop(largest)
second_largest = drop_largest.groupby(['ClientHostID']).first()
df['ratio'] = largest['LoginDaysSum'] / second_largest['LoginDaysSum']
```

When I try this I get errors all over so this is totally pseudo just to get the general vibe of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I would appreciate any input,
Thank you,

Comment: BTW, you have some typos in your expected output; Ed's answer shows the correct ratios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cut your initial df to just the top 2 rows of interest since it's sorted and then do the following:

```
In [136]:
stripped = df.groupby('ClientHostID').head(2)
stripped

Out[136]:
    ClientHostID  LoginDaysSum
0             70             4
1             70             2
2             71            11
3             71             2
4             79            37
5             79             1
7             80            18
8             80             6
9             87            29
10            87             1
11            88            88
12            88             2
```

Then `groupby` on the reduced df and just `div` the `first` and `last`:

```
In [138]:   stripped.groupby('ClientHostID').first().div(stripped.groupby('ClientHostID').last())
Out[138]:
              LoginDaysSum
ClientHostID              
70                     2.0
71                     5.5
79                    37.0
80                     3.0
87                    29.0
88                    44.0
```

You can then call `reset_index` and chain a call to `rename` to get the desired output:

```
In [140]:
stripped.groupby('ClientHostID').first().div(stripped.groupby('ClientHostID').last()).reset_index().rename(columns={'LoginDaysSum':'ratio'})

Out[140]:
   ClientHostID  ratio
0            70    2.0
1            71    5.5
2            79   37.0
3            80    3.0
4            87   29.0
5            88   44.0
```